Unity merge two project
i have two different project in unity with some common scripts in both project. Now in second project did some changes in those common script in implementation according to project functionalities. Now i want a common way to merge the changes i'll make in first project are automatically comes in second project.
I want changes done originally in the second projects as it is and new changes i made in first project combine.
Can anyone help me with this ?
Try to use gits but both project are different so.

This sounds like a job of git submodule

In such a case you should split up the code/assets

Project A
Project B
Common/Shared Stuff

There are different approaches - each has its own (dis)advantages.

Project Repositories + Submodule
One way could be to split out the common part of code/assets etc into a git submodule into 3 separate git repositories

Project A / embeds Submodule
Project B / embeds Submodule
Submodule

in that case you can basically embed the submodule at any place you wish into your main repositories - for instance as a subfolder of Assets.
You continue working on one project just like before, but whenever you happen to change something in that dedicated submodule folder the change will not be tracked directly in your project repository(/ies) but rather in the submodule repository. However, a decent git UI will flag that you have changes int he submodule you might want to commit and push first to stay in sync.

advantage: easy to reuse this way. submodule content can directly be edited. And the different projects do not immediately have to adapt to changes. Submodules can be consumed on different commits, meaning while you already changed something for project A, you can leave project B on an older state until you decide to adopt there as well.
disadvantage: submodules are a bit controversial - some hate them, others swear on them ;) You have to get used to them in order to use them properly.


Project repositories + Unity package
A very similar way - but not necesarilly using submodules you can move your shared code/assets into a custom package. There are then many ways to consume such a package but in your case you could

Either host them as separate repositories

Then you can directly install the package from git

advantage: It is read only within the projects so you can't easily break compatibility with one of the projects. As above both projects can use different states.
disadvantage: It is read-only -> every change has to be explicitly done on the package repository


Or you could again embed it into the Packages folder e.g. again via git submodule in both projects so you can directly modify the content

advantage: You can directly modify the package. Projects can use different states.
disadvantage: You can directly modify the package without noticing. E.g. when using some IDE automatic refactoring etc




Or depending on your exact setup you could host both projects and the package in the same repository in a repository structure like e.g.
root
|-- CommonPackage
|-- Projects
    |-- Project A
    |-- Project B

in this case you would embed your package as a local package via relative file path

advantage: all in one place
disadvantage: eventually harder reusing the stuff in yet another project (you could still split it out in that case easily though). Also repository size might become an issue. Projects can not use different states! (This might or might not be an advantage as well though to not allow them to grow into different directions!)




Projects + Package/Submodule Fork
To make it even more complex ^^ both the above could even be combined/extended with using a Fork for the second project. That means they could take slightly different directions which are not supposed to be fully aligned all them time but you can still have some fixes etc in the base package/submodule and could then decide in the forked one, whether and which changes to adapt and which not.

I don't think that this is possible because Unity stores it's project files on your computer, and all Unity Dashboatd applications only work for one project at a time.
Maybe you could write an external script (like batch) that merches the projects to your liking, but I don't think that this is very efficient.
My best solution for this would be to just finish a script in one Project and copy it over to the other one.
